# How to determine the unit-step response of a $h(t)=\frac{t}{1+t^2}\theta(t)$

Tags: convolution

I have this function  $h(t)=\frac{t}{1+t^2}\theta(t)$, and I have to find its unit step response. By the use of [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/312519/how-to-determine-the-step-response-using-convolution-of-the-signals-impulse-res) I took the convolution of the function, $h(t)$, which I consider composed of two convolving functions, $\frac{t}{1+t^2}$ and the unit step function, $\theta(t)$. So the convolution theorem gives

\begin{equation}
\int_0^t\theta(t-\tau)\frac{\tau}{1+\tau^2}d\tau
\end{equation}

However, there are two issues I am not sure about, first, how does one remove $\theta(t-\tau)$ and include it in the boundaries instead? Then, once this is done, assuming I am right, I get:

\begin{equation}
\int_0^t \frac{\tau}{1+\tau^2}d\tau=t \arctan t-\int_0^t\arctan\tau d\tau=\arctan\tau-\big[ t\arctan t-\frac{1}{2}\ln |1+t^2| \big]_0^t=\frac{1}{2}\big(\ln|1+t^2|-\ln1\big)
\end{equation}

When I plot this I get

[image]

But this does not seem right, when the plot of the function $h(t)$ is:

[image]

The part before zero should be different in the first plot, not gradually decreasing?

Where is the error in this procedure?

Thanks

UPDATE:

Correction: have to multiply in $\theta(t)$

\begin{equation}
\int_0^t \frac{\tau}{1+\tau^2}d\tau=t \arctan t-\int_0^t\arctan\tau d\tau=\arctan\tau-\big[ t\arctan t-\frac{1}{2}\ln |1+t^2| \big]_0^t=\frac{1}{2}\big(\ln|1+t^2|\big)\theta(t)
\end{equation}

Gives the plot

[image]

Which by Mathematica codes is still different:

[image]

Comment: Isn't the step response of $h(t)=\frac{t}{1+t^2}\theta(t)$ $\left[\theta(t)\cdot h(t)\right](u)=\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty\theta(t)\,h(t-u)\,dt=\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty\theta(t)\,\frac{u-t}{1+(u-t)^2}\theta(u-t)\,dt$?

Comment: Or viceversa? I did vice versa, and it should work, but I think I forgot to add a "theta(t)" to that answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The step response is given by the convolution

$$y(t) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty\theta(t-s)\dfrac{s}{1+s^2}\theta(s)\mathrm{d}s=\dfrac{t-s}{1+(t-s)^2}\theta(t-s)\theta(s)\mathrm{d}s.$$

The first expression is much easier to consider and reduces to

$$y(t)=\int_0^t\dfrac{s}{1+s^2}\mathrm{d}s=\dfrac{1}{2}[\log(1+s^2)]^t_0\theta(t)=\dfrac{1}{2}\log(1+t^2)\theta(t).$$